# NSURL crashing when apostrophe in string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl, nscharacterset

I am posting to a `NSURL` using the new `NSCharacterSet` to allow spaces and different characters which would otherwise cause the app to crash upon posting. I have come across an issue, whenever I have an `apostrophe(')` in the text I am posting it causes the app to crash. Code below is what I am using to convert the text box to post it. I have tried most characters and nothing causes it to crash so I don't understand why the apostrophe does. Anyone come across the same issue??

```
NSString *text = [self.textbox.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to what I asked, it was nothing to do with the objective c itself but the php I was posting to. You cannot insert a single apostrophe into a mysql database so you need to replace the apostrophe with a double and it will show as a single.

You can do this with the following code:

```
NSString *newmessage = [self.textbox.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"
                                     withString:@"''"];
```

I hope this will help anyone with a similar issue.